# Stability of linear systems with singular state matrix

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, matrix-equations, optimal-control

Given a linear time invariant system $\dot X(t) = AX(t)$ where $X \in {R^{n \times 1}}$ and $A \in {R^{n \times n}}$ is a singular matrix ($A$ has at least one zero eigenvalue). How can I study the stability of this system without computing the eigenvalues? Is it possible to apply Lyapunov theorems?

Comment: See related question:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469019/how-does-the-singularity-of-a-system-matrix-affect-the-systems-stability/469169#469169

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , You can use Lyapunov theory, to comment on stability of a system ..
for instance check whether $\frac{d V}{d t}<0$ or $\le 0$ using a Lyapunov function such as $V(x)=x^{\rm T}Px$ , where $P=P^{\rm T}>0$ and $Q=Q^{\rm T}>0$ that meets the condition $A^{\rm T}P+PA=-Q$. Alternatively you can set $Q$ as an identity matrix, which is positive definite and with know $A$ matrix calculate $P$. With one eigen value zero I guess you cant expect asymptotic stability, but can check for neutral stability. Please read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469019/how-does-the-singularity-of-a-system-matrix-affect-the-systems-stability?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer for a beautiful explanation on neutral stability.

Answer (score 1):

Use a coordinate transformation to put $A$ in Jordan form. This will let you better understand the stable, unstable, and marginally stable directions in the state space.